# Maximizing a certain integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ and $g:[0,1]\to (0,\infty)$ be smooth functions ($g$ is strictly positive). Define $\varphi:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ by $$\varphi(t)=t^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^1 g(x)e^{-\frac{f(x)}{t}}dx.$$

Suppose we know that $\varphi$ attains a maximum (for example, when $f$ and $g$ are constant), and let it be attained at $t^{\ast}\in (0,\infty)$, i.e. $$\varphi(t^{\ast})=\max_{t\in (0,\infty)}\varphi(t).$$

*What is the maximum of $\varphi$ and what is $t^{\ast}$ in terms of $f$ and $g$?*

My attempt: differentiate under the integral sign: $$\frac{d\varphi}{dt}=\frac{1}{2t^{5/2}}\int_0^1(2f(x)-t)g(x)e^{-\frac{f(x)}{t}}dx.$$ Therefore $t$ is a maximum iff $d\varphi/dt=0$ which is true iff $$t=\frac{2\int_0^1f(x)g(x)e^{-\frac{f(x)}{t}}dx}{\int_0^1g(x)e^{-\frac{f(x)}{t}}dx}.$$ Now I'm stuck. How can I solve for t?

Wolfram spat out something about the Lambert $W$ function, but I'm not familiar with that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: I made it up myself